# Array of dates React Native as Today-Tomorrow

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, date

I want to make a list in React Native which shows dates like (let's say today is Monday):

**`Today - Tomorrow - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday - Saturday - Sunday - Monday`** <- i need to show seven days

And when I click one of the items it should return the date itself, say for `Friday` should be `16.07.2021` or any other format.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use momentjs library,

https://momentjs.com/

something like this should work

```html
import moment from 'moment'

const returnDates = () => {
    const weekArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    const today = new Date()
    return weekArray.map(week => moment(today).add(week, 'days').calendar().split(' at')[0] )
}
```

tested

[image]

Comment: This really worked. 
All i did was to change the mapping to: `weekArray.map(week => array.push({ value: moment(today).add(week, 'days'), day: moment(today).add(week, 'days').calendar().split(' at')[0] }))` so i could also have the date itself. Thanks for saving me, i was trying some sort of for loop which didn't really worked.
Thank you